# Angular JS - Animating md-chips element on enter and leave

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-animate

I'm trying to animate chips created by md-chips, angular-material, but it does not work.

here is my css codes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.md-chip.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
    animation-name: zoomIn;
}
.md-chip.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomOut;
    animation-name: zoomOut;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<md-chips class="custom-chips" ng-show="elems.length" ng-model="elems" readonly="true">
    <md-chip-template>
        <span>
            <strong>{{$chip.name}}</strong>
        </span>
    </md-chip-template>
    <button md-chip-remove class="md-primary">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="md-close"></md-icon>
    </button>
</md-chips>
```

but no animation showing and everything goes normal!
I read some tutorials and whatever they said step by step but i think it's not gonna work with md-chips work some reasons.

Comment: can you create a plunker for the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a duration, for example:

```
.md-chip.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
    animation-name: zoomIn;

    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Or simply:

```
.md-chip.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: zoomIn 1s;
  animation: zoomIn 1s;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/L36jyc3WFW9cRuu4Cybs?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on tasseKATT's answer, if you add `max-height` property to the animation to go from `max-height: 0px;` to `max-height: 50px;` (for example), then the content will not be so jumpy when a the last chip from a row is removed, or when another chip is added and it creates another row.

See sample below for css and the **demo** on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECH1eIWvSuwZcjpbk9J2) (just a fork):

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
        from {
          max-height: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
            transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        }

        50% {
          max-height: 50px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @keyframes zoomIn {
        from {
          max-height: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
            transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        }

        50% {
          max-height: 50px;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes zoomOut {
        from {
          max-height: 50px;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
            transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        }

        to {
          max-height: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    @keyframes zoomOut {
        from {
          max-height: 50px;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
            transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
        }

        to {
          max-height: 0px;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    .md-chip.ng-enter {
        -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
        animation-name: zoomIn;

        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation: zoomIn 1s;
        animation: zoomIn 1s;
    }

    .md-chip.ng-leave {
        -webkit-animation-name: zoomOut;
        animation-name: zoomOut;

        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }
```